# Linear subspace of normed space

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, proof-verification

> Let $X$ be a normed space and $A  \subset  X$ such that $X \setminus A$ is a linear subspace of $X$. Show that A is either dense or empty set.

Can someone check my proof?

If $A$ is empty set we have no work to do. Assume that $A$ is not dense in $X$ and let $x \in X \setminus A$. Since $A$ is not dense we can find $r_x>0$ such that $B(x,r_x) \subset X \setminus A$. Let $d=\operatorname{dist} \left( B(x,r_x),A \right)$, Hence $X \setminus A$ is linear subspace then $B \left(x ,\frac{2d}{r_x} \cdot r_x \right)=B(x,2d) \subset X \setminus A$ but this is contradiction since we defined $d$ as distance between $B(x,r_x)$ and $A$.

Comment: Alternatively, you can show that any subspace that contains an open set must be the entire space.

Comment: Thanks, so I understand that my proof is correct?